# How Can i Adjust the Highlight Entire row into A-H only Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I Use this code please help me tweak it into highligh A-H and not the entire row.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'Update 20140318
Static xRow
Static xColumn
If xColumn <> "" Then

    With Rows(xRow).Interior
        .colorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End If
pRow = Selection.Row
pColumn = Selection.Column
xRow = pRow
xColumn = pColumn
With Rows(pRow).Interior
    .colorIndex = 6
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean change interior cell colour when you say highlight?

Comment: do not clutter up code by using `with ... end with` for one line .... use `Rows(xRow).Interior.colorIndex = xlNone` instead .... similar for the other

Comment: How about you don't apply the Interior color to the whole row?? Just to the cells you want to apply the color to? Hint! Hint!

Comment: `range("a" & prow & ":h" & prow).interior.....`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
With Rows(pRow).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 6
End With
```

try

```
Range("A" & pRow & ":H" & pRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Target.EntireRow.Columns("a:h").Interior.ColorIndex = 6

End Sub
```